# How to get the last executed thread identifier?

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling, sampling

I'm currently developing a sampling profiling tool for our online service written in Python.

My approach so far is to have a dedicated thread that, at regular intervals, looks at all the running Python threads and analyses their current  frames. The code works well but sadly it doesn't reflect the collaborative thread nature of (C)Python where only one given thread is really running (and has the GIL) at a given time. I'd like to get the frames of only the last running thread at each loop.

I've seen other tools using `signal.setitimer` to regularly call a signal on the process and fetching the current thread identifier with `thread.get_ident()`. Because apparently we like to live in a world of pain, we have to make the tool work on Windows, where `signal.setitimer`is not an option.

Is there a way in Python to get the previously running thread identifier from another thread ? Writing a C extension is okay with me if that can help me.